# Entity Framework model.edmx and many to many relationships

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In the database I have 3 tables, User, Group and a lookup table UserGroup which contains UserID and GroupId.

I create a model.edmx and this allows me to:
var users = context.User
var groups = context.Group
but does not create an object for context.UserGroup.

what is the syntax for getting all the users in a group, and all the groups that a user belongs to?

```
var results = from groups in db.Groups.Where(t => t.Users(u => u.UserID ==1))
select groups;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the proper keys setup, EF will hide away your junction table, and create a navigation property to make the connection between the tables

For getting all the groups a user belongs to:

```
var groupResults = db.Groups.Where(g => g.Users.Select(u => g.UserId).Contains(userId));
```

and for getting all the Users:

```
var userResults = db.Users.Where(u => u.Groups.Select(g => g.GroupId).Contains(groupId));
```

Comment: No, the g.UserID does not exist, and vica versa.

Comment: Updated the code - it's not pretty, but you can select the id's for each group and then if the user is in there return it

Comment: how junction table is hidden ? @MarkOreta.

I have to join 3 tables,all the three tables have fields `ID (pk); Name;IsActive`, my junction table is

`OrganizationSateCities
-OrganizationID
-StateID
-CityID`

how can I achieve this ? Currently its not hiding junction table instead showing a collection of `OrganizationSateCities` in `object` of `Organization`

Answer (score 0):

The junction table will not be created. You'll get two navigation collection properties. Groups in User entity and Users in Group entity.

To get all users from a group:

```
var usersInGroup = context.Groups.Where(g => g.ID == groupId).SelectMany(g => g.Users);
```

To get all groups the user belongs to:

```
var groupsOfUser = context.Users.Where(u => u.ID == userId).SelectMany(u => u.Groups);
```